# If an parabola has its focus at the (a,b) and has directrix at x=c....

Tags: conic-sections

If an parabola has its focus at the (a,b) and has directrix at x=c, what would the equation 4p(x – h) = (y – k)^2 look like in terms of a,b, and c?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|a-c|=2p$, $a+c=2h$, and $b=k.$  Try also drawing a general graph.